# Why can't events be invoked or their invocation list set from outside of the declaring class

Tags: c#, .net, events

Interview question: Why can't events be invoked and their invocation list set from outside of the declaring class?

I found explanation to the first part of the question in this post [Events Invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222588/events-invocation)

I assume the answer for the second part lies with security. 
Are there any other reasons considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the class is the owner of those events.

We say that example in OOPS should be taken from real world examples. So if you are an entity and you do an event of let's say raising your hand, would you like to keep the authority of raising your hand with yourself or give to someone else?

But there is a [catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107972/calling-c-sharp-events-from-outside-the-owning-class)

Comment: Makes sense but what about setting the invocation list?

Answer (score 6):

A keyword your interviewer may be looking for is **encapsulation**.

Events are only supposed to expose **subscribe** and **unsubscribe** operations to potential subscribers. Invocation is really the responsibility of the class that exposes the event.

Also keep in mind that `public event EventHandler FooBar;` is a short form of the following syntax

```
private EventHandler _fooBar;

public event EventHandler FooBar
{
    add
    {
        _fooBar = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(_fooBar, value);
    }
    remove
    {
        _fooBar = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(_fooBar, value);
    }
}
```

See [Event Accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx)

Comment: Actually, the delegate is given the same name as the event--a convention which I hate (IMHO, `EventName(Params)` shouldn't be a direct delegate invocation--it should include the appropriate null check logic, since raising an event with no subscribers is a perfectly legitimate thing to do).

Answer (score 1):

A C# short-format event declaration direct the compiler to declare a field of delegate type which, for unfortunate historical reasons, is given the same name as the event.  Because the field declaration is generated by the compiler, rather than being part of user code, there is no means by which its scope can be set to anything other than `private`.  If you wish to have the delegate or delegates associated with an event be accessible to child classes, then it's necessary to use something like the form shown by Brandon Cuff (though perhaps guarded with an `Interlocked.CompareExchange`).